# No qualifying bean, expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, citrus-framework

I searched on both the internet and on stack overlow but can't seem to find a solution to my problem:

```
Unable to find bean reference for type 'class com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient'Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: server1BasicAuthClient,server2BasicAuthClient
```

To sketch some background information: I have to make a small application using Spring 5 and Citrus Framework to automate our integration tests.

I defined as following my Beans:

```
@Configuration 
public class EndpointAuthentication {

public String server1Host;

public int server1Port;

public String server2Host;

public int server2Port;

@Bean(name="server1BasicAuthClient")
public com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient server1BasicAuthClient() throws Exception {
    return CitrusEndpoints.http()
            .client()
            .requestUrl(String.format("http://%s:%s/", server1Host, server1Port))
            .requestFactory(sslRequestFactory(server1Host,server1Port))
            .build();
}

@Bean(name="server2BasicAuthClient")
public com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient server2BasicAuthClient() throws Exception {
    return CitrusEndpoints.http()
            .client()
            .requestUrl(String.format("http://%s:%s/", server2Host, server2Port))
            .requestFactory(sslRequestFactory(server2Host,server2Port))
            .build();
}
}
```

And I tried to inject my Bean like this,

```
public class AuthenticationIT {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("server1BasicAuthClient")
@CitrusEndpoint
private HttpClient server1BasicAuthClient;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("server2BasicAuthClient")
@CitrusEndpoint
private HttpClient server2BasicAuthClient;
....
}
```

Any ideas where and how to fix the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you autowiring the type `HttpClient` anywhere else? You can try marking one of the `@Bean` methods with `@Primary`.

Comment: Please show code for the solution that worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250 @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

@Autowired applies to fields, constructors, and multi-argument methods, allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level. By contrast, @Resource is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.

---

Try to set using `value` instead of `name` OR use @Primary

```
@Bean(value="server1BasicAuthClient")
@Bean(value="server2BasicAuthClient")
```

[Refer 1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) [Refer 2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Primary and resource annotations works for me. I changed my implementation to use a resource annotation.